# Reversing and Splitting all nibbles in an IPv6 Address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ipv6, terraform

I'd like to automatically create an IPv6 reverse hosted zone for my module in Terraform. AWS automatically assigns `/54` network spaces for VPCs which request them.

Assuming that `3731:54:65fe:2::a7/54` is my network CIDR block, I'd need to create a reverse hosted zone at:

```
7.a.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.0.0.0.e.f.5.6.4.5.0.0.1.3.7.3.ip6.arpa
```

Since it's not possible to request a given IPv6 block in AWS, I need some way in Terraform to expand the above CIDR block, split it into nibbles, and reverse it. I can't see a way in Terraform to do this right now.

I will probably file a bug with Terraform to report this. Has anyone needed to or was able to accomplish something like this?

Comment: I have reported this as a feature request [here in the Terraform GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16942).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a program that takes your CIDR block as input, constructs your reverse lookup, and then outputs the result. Then you can use that program in terraform by using terraform's external datasource: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html

You'll have to make your program take input and generate output in the specific way that terraform requires for it to work correctly.

Comment: Is it possible to map variables into the query parameter? I'll have to try it out.